# Columnas Dinámicas SQL-Server

Tags: sql

Necesito un Query que hasta la fecha nunca he realizado, Tengo dos tablas:

```
Tabla A:

id_producto, (datos del producto)

Tabla B:

id_producto, imagen.
```

Bien en la `tabla A` tengo toda la información del producto, y en la `tabla B` tengo las imágenes ( máximo por cada producto tengo 4 imágenes), el requerimiento es que, aparezca la información del producto y 4 columnas adicionales, cada una con una imagen distinta del producto y en caso de no tenerla no importa que salga null.

ejemplo:

```
Tabla A:
------------------------------------------
id_producto | tipo |        nombre       |
------------------------------------------
1           | Reloj|     reloj deportivo |

Tabla B:
----------------------------
id_producto | imagen          |
-----------------------------
1           | imgp1.jpg       |
-----------------------------
1           | imgp1_2.jpg     |
-----------------------------
1           | imgp1_3.jpg     |
-----------------------------
1           | imgp1_4.jpg     |


y El resultado necesito que sea así:

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
id_producto | tipo |   imagen1    | imagen2   |     imagen3 |   imagen4
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           | reloj | imgp1.jpg   |imgp1_2.jpg |imgp1_3.jpg  |imgp1_4.jpg
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: qué tipo de datos es la columna `imagen`?

Comment: 2 preguntas: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Por qué las filas de la Tabla B tienen que ser columnas en el resultado?

Comment: 1) es tipo texto, .... 2) hice un inner join y pues me muestra una fila por cada imágen, es que el requerimiento del cliente es un solo registro del producto pero todas las imágenes en columnas continuas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varias formas de hacerlo, una de ellas es una simple agregación y una expresión `CASE`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  A.id_producto,
            A.tipo,
            B.imagen,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A.id_producto ORDER BY B.imagen)
    FROM dbo.TablaA A
    LEFT JOIN dbo.TablaB B
        ON A.id_producto = B.id_producto
)
SELECT  id_producto,
        MIN(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN imagen END) imagen1,
        MIN(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN imagen END) imagen2,
        MIN(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN imagen END) imagen3,
        MIN(CASE WHEN RN = 4 THEN imagen END) imagen4
FROM CTE
GROUP BY id_producto
;
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

[Acá hay un demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e427bd56048ca80b8aa170552fdafd6d) de esto, y los resultados son:

```
╔═════════════╦═══════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╗
║ id_producto ║  imagen1  ║   imagen2   ║   imagen3   ║   imagen4   ║
╠═════════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╣
║           1 ║ imgp1.jpg ║ imgp1_2.jpg ║ imgp1_3.jpg ║ imgp1_4.jpg ║
╚═════════════╩═══════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╝
```

Comment: Hey @Lamak Según la pregunta, al `id_producto = 1` le corresponden las 4 imágenes, en tu ejemplo estas asignando una sola imagen por id, o me equivoco?

Comment: @J.Rodríguez en efecto tu interpretación del código no es correcta. En caso de que el producto tenga 4 imágenes, las 4 van a aparecer. La condición que estoy poniendo en la expresión `CASE` no es `id_producto = 1` es `RN = 1`, que es el resultado de `ROW_NUMBER` para ese producto

Comment: Cierto no me fije que dice `RN = 1` tienes razón.

Comment: Wooooow ! acá es dónde me doy cuenta que no sé aún nada de SQL y eso que trabajo ya 2 años con estas cosas, omg, te lo agradezco mucho y aunque la verdad no entiendo demasiado el código, la adapté a mi necesidad, Mil gracias.

Comment: @J.Rodríguez Agregué un demo con el código de esto para que lo puedas probar, de todas formas

Comment: @AndressBlend espero esto te sea de utilidad: https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SQL_Tutorial :D

Comment: Muchas gracias :D !!!

Comment: de nada bro, sigue elevando ese cosmos y dale con todo el power 2.0!!! :D