# como crear una tabla SQL con columnas dinamicas

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure, sql-server-2014

Como puedo hacer un **SP** dinamico donde de acuerdo a los datos de una **tabla1** los tome como columnas para crear una **tabla2** estos pueden variar.

Es decir como puede haber 1 o 2 puede haber 10,20,30... parto de un **SP** para crear una tabla

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CrearTablaResources] 
-- Aqui van los paramentros

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT 
create table Resources(
Id int Primary key Identity(1,1),
ResourceId int not null,
ResourceName varchar(max) not 
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Hace unos días formularon esta pregunta sobre [Columnas Dinámicas SQL-Server](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/146230/69447)
 aquí en SO, quizás te pueda servir.

De lo contrario aquí le escribo una pequña solución alternativa que puede **usar como guía** para lo que requiere, creo que podría funcionar.

Puede crear SQL dinámico algo como esto:

- Enviar el nombre de la tabla como parámetro al `SP`
- Enviar `DataTable` con  `NombreColumna`, `TipoDato` al `SP` (tabla definida por el usuario)

Para enviar lista, datatable necesita crear TABLA DEFINIDA POR EL USUARIO

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[MiColumnaTipoDato] AS TABLE(
    NombreColumna [NVARCHAR](200) NULL,
    TipoDato [NVARCHAR](200) NULL
);
```

Luego, en el `SP`, cree el cursor para recorrer la tabla y haga su declaración de SQL dinámico.

```
Create Procedure sp_CrearTablasDinamicas(
@NombreTabla nvarchar(150),
@EsquemaTabla [MiColumnaTipoDato] readonly
)
AS BEGIN
 DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

 set @SQL= N' Create table '+QUOTENAME(@NombreTabla);

 set  @SQL =@SQL+ ' Aquí se repite sobre @EsquemaTabla para agregar N Columnas '

 EXECUTE sp_executesql  @sql
END
```

> Como referencia [QUOTENAME](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) fue específicamente diseñado para citar nombres de columnas / tablas / bases de datos - sysnames. Por ejemplo, esto: `SELECT QUOTENAME('abc[]def')` devuelve `[abc[]]def]` mientras `SELECT '[' + 'abc[]def' + ']'` devuelve `[abc[]def]` que no es válido para usar como una columna / tabla / nombre de la base de datos.